# Deploying flutter web on IIS server is throwing Error 404 Resource not found for every page except index.html

Tags: flutter

I have multiple Flutter pages like `homePage`, `OfferPage`, `ProfilePage`, and when building the flutter project with `flutter build web`, the build is generated without any errors, and I can see `main.dart.js` generated.

However, when navigating to the URL with https://xxxx.com/homePage, I am getting a `404` error, but https://xxxx.com/ displays correctly. Am I missing something? I cannot see the separate page `js` file created anywhere.

Comment: A webserver must be able to be configured to deliver any would-be 404 to index.html.  That's different for different servers.

Comment: But https://xxxx.com/homePage  should open the homePage

Comment: The design of web build is that the app is always in index.html, which is expected to be served as the directory index, as well as any 404s that happen.  If your webserver is configured like that, and you have something like go-router to interpret your incoming URL as a route to your home page, it should just work.

Comment: Thanks i got it resolved by adding web.config file.

Comment: I am also facing similar problem, Can you provide the instruction to add web.config file for flutter web application on IIS

Comment: @JigarNagda If possible then please provide us the web.config file or at least provide the instructions means, what content exactly we need to write in web.config file to resolve this issue.

Comment: @jeeva If possible then please provide us the web.config file or at least provide the instructions means, what content exactly we need to write in web.config file to resolve this issue.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz If possible then please provide us the web.config file or at least provide the instructions means, what content exactly we need to write in web.config file to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and following code fixed for me. Put this into web.config and add to the root folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="SPA Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <!-- Exclude requests for existing files or directories -->
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <!-- Rewrite all other URLs to the root URL -->
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```